# El término 'mvnw.cmd' no se reconoce como nombre de un cmdlet

Tags: java, spring-boot, vscode, maven

cuando ejecuto el comando

```
mvnw.cmd spring-boot:run
```

me sale el siguiente error:

> mvnw.cmd : El término 'mvnw.cmd' no se reconoce como nombre de un cmdlet, función, archivo de script o programa ejecutable. Compruebe si escribió correctamente el nombre o, si
> incluyó una ruta de acceso, compruebe que dicha ruta es correcta e inténtelo de nuevo.

Alguien sabe como solucionarlo? Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Tienes la ruta de maven metida en las rutas de tu entorno? Porque un pc no hace magia... Le tienes que enseñar tú donde están las cosas. De hecho, si simplemente buscas el error que te da en google te salen mil páginas con cómo se soluciona... No veo la necesidad de añadir la mil uno aquí así de primeras.

Comment: Si, ya revisé muchísimas páginas con soluciones y ninguna me funcionó. Lo que hice: agregué las variables de entorno "java_home" y "maven_home" y sus respectivos paths en PATH. luego como no funcionó, habilité los scripts desde powershell con Set-ExecutionPolicy  dejando CurrentUser y LocalMachine en "Unrestricted". Y sigue sin correr Java en VSCode...  Ahhh y desinstalé y volví a instalar el visual studio code.

Comment: ¿probaste con `mvn spring-boot:run`? ¿Agregaste al Path `%MAVEN_HOME%\bin`?

Comment: como lo resolvistes al final igual tengo el mismo problema

Answer (score -1):

La solución es la siguiente:

```
.\mvnw.cmd spring-boot:run
```

Comment: Tu respuesta es solo codigo. Por favor mira [answer]. Se pide que expliques que hace este código (mas alla que a ti vos te parezca obvio, puede que otro usuario no lo vea tan simple).