# cuando ejecuto el comando "mvnw.cmd spring-boot:run" me sale el siguiente error: como lo soluciono

Tags: java, maven

[image: codigo en visual code]

"mvnw.cmd spring-boot:run" tengo error

Comment: Has probado de buscar este error en google por si a caso no vaya a ser que alguien ha tenido antes este error y existe alguna especia de directrices o minitutorial para solucionarlo ? Sin ir mas lejos, en esta misma comunidad hay más de un hilo que es presenta la misma duda https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/560698/problemas-con-java-y-vscode